# Symfony Twig Customize Radio Buttons

Tags: forms, symfony, radio-button, twig, material-design

I wanted to ask you how can I customize my radio buttons from a symfony form to a radio button like this Material Design one:

http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#toggles-section/radio

What I already have is this:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

   {% block choice_widget_expanded %}
      <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
         {% for child in form.status %}
            {{ form_widget(child, { 'attr': {'class': 'mdl-radio__button', 'name': 'options'}}) }}
            {{ form_label(child) }}
         {% endfor %}
      </div>
   {% endblock %}
```

I try to change the **name** **attribute** like you can see but it doesn't change. So how can I do this without breaking the form? And additionally how can I add a HTML element after the input element?

I appreciate your help!

In the end it should look like this to work:

**Radio button one**

```
<label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="option-1">
  <input type="radio" id="option-1" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="0" checked />
  <span class="mdl-radio__label">Yes</span>
</label>
```

**Radio button two**

```
<label class="mdl-radio mdl-js-radio mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="option-2">
   <input type="radio" id="option-2" class="mdl-radio__button" name="options" value="1" />
   <span class="mdl-radio__label">No</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Take a look here http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html